# How to make Rails respond to only ONE request in the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Our project is using Ext-js, and sometimes will send several request to Rails.
This will cause an error:

> A copy of XX has been removed from the module tree...

This may be because Rails is responding to a request whilst it has to reload some module. The error disappears in production as I suspected.

I guess I can solve the problem by configuring Rails to make it respond to only ONE request at the same time, but I can't find any information about this.

Anyone know? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails is single threaded, so it's not concurrency issues that are causing that error.

Try to update Rails to the latest version. This bug should occur a lot less frequently in 2.3.4 than in older versions.